# How to set slider step values to some fixed values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm working on sliders with the jQuery sliders, I have a inout slider as

```
<form id="sliderData">
  <input id="slider1" type="range" min="0" max="50" step="">
</form>
```

I want the slider to set up to only some fixed  values as `[2,30,20,30,35,45]`. So I cannot set up the step value. I have tried to fire the event by this code

```
$('form#sliderData').change(function () {
    alert("Hello");
});
```

This event is not even firing.Is there anyway to set slider to random values

Comment: Values are not even in order!

Comment: @RayonDabre that was actually his question - he want random step values!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The event is not being fired because you need to hook the change event to the slider control itself, not it's parent form.

The problem you have is that you cannot specify specific steps in a slider control. They must all be the same step apart from the min to the max values. To solve this you could instead make the values of the slider match the indexes of the values in your JS array, and have a label showing the actual option chosen. Something like this:

```js
var values = [2, 30, 20, 30, 35, 45];
$('#slider1').on('input', e => $('span').text(values[e.target.value]));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="sliderData">
  <input id="slider1" type="range" min="0" max="5" value="0">
  <span>2</span>
</form>
```

Comment: It's working for me here in Chrome. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Me too working in Chrome, I have just updated the fiddle with what I'm doing can you take a look at it. https://jsfiddle.net/9916v6bh/2/

Comment: Your fiddle hadn't changed the `min`, `max` or `value` of the slider in the HTML.You can also use DOM traversal to find the span to update instead of hacking together a data attribute selector. Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/9916v6bh/3/

Comment: Use oninput instead of onchange to make the slider more responsive. See example here: https://jsfiddle.net/7qs8ota3/